# Order posts by price

Tags: order

I have a list of products on a page and am trying to order them by a custom field called "price". Unfortunately, $3,950,000 is coming before $349,000. I've used a couple of codes but neither one is working. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Here's the first code I've tried.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'price', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```

Here's the other code I've tried.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num+0', 'meta_key' => 'price', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing your "price" (apparently) as human readable formatted currency. That makes it a string. And that means it is going to be sorted alphabetically, more or less, and not numerically as you need it to be. If you can store those values without the punctuation, and use `meta_value_num`-- your second query above (but I am not sure you need the "+0") -- I think you will have what you want.

Comment: That works! Thank you. Now I just need to find some code that will put the commas back in after the query.

Comment: PHP's [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) should get you a long way.

Comment: Make sure you use WordPress's i18n version of number format, so you get the internationalization benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Good Reference from below link:

> https://therichpost.com/wordpress-query-to-get-woocommerce-products-order-by-sales-pricing-and-rating/

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'asc',
'meta_key' => '_price'
```